# How do I (mount and) copy the contents of (hidden) WinRE?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a WinRE partition at the end of my SSD and I want to move it down following the Win NTFS system partition so I can install Linux in the fourth position.

This SuperUser suggests copying the contents of WinRE.
https://superuser.com/a/1233758

*I would recommend assigning a drive letter to it and obtaining a copy of the WinRE.wim file. You'll need it to move the recovery environment somewhere later. You can obtain a copy of this file in other ways, but it will be easier just to get it ahead of time.*

[How to make a hidden partition visible](https://superuser.com/a/459444) says how to launch Disk Management to access Admin Privileges. But the steps say to right click on the hidden partition, but Disk Management never give me anything more than “help” popup.

How do I copy the contents of WinRE?

Comment: Can I ask the reason you care which order the partitions exist in because you can have more then 4 partitions.  “How do I copy the contents of WinRE?” - Use DISM to apply the .wim to the partition

Comment: You have to use disk part within a command prompt to assign a drive letter to a partition like the recovery partition

Comment: 1) I care only because when I added the new partition, Parted complained my partitions were out of order. 2) I'm not up on Win package terminology. Is *Use DISM to apply the .wim to the partition* an alternative to copying the existing WinRE? Assign a letter--is that all that's required? What utility would you use to copy the contents?

Comment: You can use DISM to extract the winre.wim from a windows installation disc. Or, you can grab it from your existing recovery partition. You'll need to unhide it and/or assign a drive letter. http://defaultreasoning.com/2009/05/29/unhide-the-recovery-partition-on-a-basic-disk-with-diskpart/ once you have the WinRE.wim the best thing to do would probably be to move it to your C: drive and re-enable as described by one of the links in the post you referenced. I would not attempt to move partitions around. Just move the winre.wim and delete the recovery partition.

Comment: That link did the trick. write it and it's the answer. Thanks.